# Can I get CSS property "padding" of an element using WebDriver?

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a task to test that all over the application, spacing between the 2 input fields should be 6px.

So when I tried to read the css value using `getCssvalue` method, it is giving a blank value.

Note: `getCssvalue` method is working fine for the other properties (Eg: font-family)

Here is the screen shot of css values for one the input field containing spacing between the input fields.

[image]

Comment: When i am using getcssvalue method, blank output i am getting.

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='alias']/..")).getCssValue("padding"));

Comment: Are you sure that you obtained correct element? There is no `input` on the screenshot.

Comment: 'input' is within 'td'. And it's working fine for "font-size", It's not working only for "Padding"

Comment: `getCs‌​sValue` returns css value of particular element. If you define `padding` in `td`, you need to call the method on `td` element.

Comment: Now i am calling the getCssvalue method on 'td' only.(see the ".." in XPATH)

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Anyway, in my opinion you should change your question showing your attempts with getCs‌​sValue and describing that the problem affects only some particular styles.

Comment: @ArturMalinowski Thanks for the early response. I got the answer. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters specified as shorthand property are decomposed into individuals. Try:

```
element.getCs‌​sValue("padding-top");
element.getCs‌​sValue("padding-bottom");
...
```

instead of shorthand form. See [docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29).